# How do I wait for all images in a specific jQuery selection to load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use the following code, it runs once for each item in the selection:

```
$('.someElement img').load( function() {
    // Do something
});
```

So basically, if .someElement contains 5 images, it fires off 5 different times. How can I run an event such that it only fires off once after all images in the selection have been loaded?

Specifically, I am not wanting to wait for all images on the page. This would specifically be used for content that has been added to the DOM long after the page has rendered, and that content contains IMG tags, and I want to wait for those specific images to load. The selector will target that dynamic content.

Comment: Just spitballing.  Store `$(...).length` in a variable.  For every load event subtract 1.  Once it reaches 0, do stuff

Comment: That's a cool idea. I'm working on something similar to that now as a workaround. I guess I was just curious if there was already a built in method in jQuery or javascript or a best practice that people use for this. But yeah, I think using an iterator variable and comparing to the total count may be the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let loadCount = 0;

const images = $('.someElement img');

images.load( function() {
  loadCount++;

  if (loadCount >= images.length) {
    // Do something
  }
});
```

Comment: If you change 5 to $('.someElement img').length that would be perfect.

Comment: And I see you just edited to reflect that. I love it. Great solution!

Comment: I also shortened it by adding the iterator to the comparison: if (++loadCount >= images.length) {